# .htaccess Redirection all domains to one domai

Tags: .htaccess

How do i redirect from .in or .net and others to .com only. Here's what i tried

```
RewriteEngine on 
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do i make this to work for subdomains also?
Example:

```
http://subdomain.mysite.in/app/rest-of-the-url
http://subdomain.mysite.net/app/rest-of-the-url
```

Should go to

```
http://subdomain.mysite.com/app/rest-of-the-url
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.(?!com).+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Add `(?!com)` to the rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.(?!com).+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this is working fine except in one case

https://www.mysite.net/app/xyz is not getting redirected to https://www.mysite.com/app/xyz

Comment: The above rule would work but switch to http://. If you have similar requirements but need to support SSL as well, please post your requirements as a question. I would be happy to help you out with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason you should be combining these into a single rule. You should address the main domain, sans "www", then the subdomain with different TLDs separately.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.mysite\.([^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdomain.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```